# Actor Model Frameworks For Embedded Development Proven for Prime Time

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, actor

What are the Actor model Frameworks for Embedded Development on linux which are proven for prime time beside Erlang?

Comment: Did you check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#Actor_libraries_and_frameworks ? I would choose a C or C++ software

Answer (score 2):

QP is a family of lightweight, open source, active object (actor) frameworks for real-time embedded systems. The family consist of QP/C, QP/C++, and QP-nano frameworks. Out of which, the QP/C and QP/C++ have been ported to Linux (P-Threads). Please check http://www.state-machine.com and http://www.state-machine.com/linux.

There is also a free graphical modeling tool called QM, which generates code for QP based on hierarchical state machine diagrams (UML Statecharts). See http://www.state-machine.com/qm.

Comment: Anything open source and free?

Comment: QP is licensed under GPL, so it is free like "free speech". It's not free like "free beer", if this is what you mean.

Comment: I understand that you are the founder of this company and can see the price sheet in here http://www.state-machine.com/licensing/index.php#Pricing. Free open-source to me is like free beer like Android!